# Problem with AWK when after changing the print order

Tags: awk

I have a problem procesing some java classes that I can't understand why it happens, it doesn't have any logic to me.

I want to extract just the attributes of each class. I have (for example) class "oplyanxp.java":

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1584084300397L;
private OTrnPrcS oTrnPrcS = new OTrnPrcS();
private OPlyAnxS oPlyAnxS;
```

and class "oplyanxs.java":

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1584084300397L;
private java.math.BigDecimal  cmpVal;
private java.lang.String  qtnVal;
private java.lang.String  plyVal;
```

I run this script for each class:

```
awk '{if (($1 == "private") && ($5 != "serialVersionUID")) {print $1" "$2" "$3}}' oplyanxp.java
awk '{if (($1 == "private") && ($5 != "serialVersionUID")) {print $1" "$2" "$3}}' oplyanxs.java
```

and the result is ok:

oplyanxp.java

```
  private OTrnPrcS oTrnPrcS
  private OPlyAnxS oPlyAnxS;
```

oplyanxs.java

```
  private java.math.BigDecimal cmpVal;
  private java.lang.String qtnVal;
  private java.lang.String plyVal;
```

but if I change the parameter print order:

```
awk '{if (($1 == "private") && ($5 != "serialVersionUID")) {print $1" "$3" "$2}}' oplyanxp.java
awk '{if (($1 == "private") && ($5 != "serialVersionUID")) {print $1" "$3" "$2}}' oplyanxs.java
```

the result for class "oplyanxs.java" is fine:

```
  private cmpVal; java.math.BigDecimal
  private qtnVal; java.lang.String
  private plyVal; java.lang.String
```

but for class "oplyanxs.java" is wrong:

```
  private oTrnPrcS OTrnPrcS
   OPlyAnxSPlyAnxS;
```

I have also another class (oplyanxcpt.java) with more.less the same problem:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1584084300397L;
private String prcTrmVal;
private List<OPlyAnxP> oPlyAnxPT;
```

---

```
awk '{if (($1 == "private") && ($5 != "serialVersionUID")) {print $1" "$2" "$3}}' oplyanxcpt.java
private String prcTrmVal;
private List<OPlyAnxP> oPlyAnxPT;
```

---

```
awk '{if (($1 == "private") && ($5 != "serialVersionUID")) {print $1" "$3" "$2}}' oplyanxcpt.java
String prcTrmVal;
List<OPlyAnxP>PT;
```

I can't understand what the problem is, why it works for a class and not for the others. All files are in utf-8 encoding.

Anybody have any idea of the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your efforts in form of code. Could you please post in a simple form of sample input and expected sample output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Just guessing: could it be a DOS/UNIX line ending problem?

Comment: also a suggestion, default OFS is a space character, so you can use `print $1, $2, $3`

Comment: Oh, seems to be that link problem Sundeep, I will test it and tell you something.

Comment: Maybe is what Sundeep sais, Poshi :)

Comment: Let me check the solution